# Changing nodes in linked list

Tags: c, list, linked-list

This is somewhat mind-boggling

i will try to explain my doubt.

Check this function for example:

```
void snoc(Lint *l, int val){
    Lint i, new;

    new = (Lint) malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    new->value = val;
    new->next = NULL;

    i=(*l);

    while(i->next!=NULL){
        i=i->next;
    }

    i->next = new;
}
```

I understand the concept behind and i have no trouble working with lists, taking in consideration that i can't iterate through the list using the list initial pointer itself (if i do this, i would lose the initial pointer right)

The  thing is, making `i=(*l)` and afterwards iterating through the list using i=i->next, is making the i variable becoming in constant change.

In this particular example, the original list will not change until i find the end of the linked list, and then i make an attribution and voilá! I insert an element at the end.

My doubt is, if by changing the `i`, and making `i->next = new` at the end, wouldn't that mean that everytime i make `i=i->next`, change ALL the nodes in the original list?

Another example would be init:

```
void init (Lint *l){
    Lint i, prev;
    i=(*l);
    prev=NULL;

    while(i!=NULL){
        if( (i->next)->next==NULL){
            i->next = NULL;
        }
        i=i->next;
    }
}
```

if i do this, the last element will be removed, by changing the `i->next` to NULL, at the right moment. But before that, i've been making changes to the `i` itself again, by telling `i=i->next`

If i were to make this change to the `(*l)` itself (by doing `(*l)=(*l)->next`) i would be ruining the original list .

I really hope you guys can understand my doubt.

Comment: Please provide the definition of `Lint`.

Comment: Definitions for `Lint` and `Nodo` would help.. I presume `Nodo` is a struct, and `Lint` is a `Nodo *`?

Comment: Please don't use "new" for variable names: Lint i, new; Or am I not understanding it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we do understand your confusion, and it comes from not working out the list pointers on a **piece of paper** so you can visualize what is taking place. Always use a diagram when you are working `node` link issues. For example in your case with your singly linked-list, current node called `i` (dubious choice of name) and your new node called `new` a helpful diagram would be:

```
Singly Linked-List (non-circular)

         Tail                 Current                Head
      (list start)               i                   new
     +------------+        +------------+        +------------+
     |   Payload  |        |   Payload  |        |   Payload  |
     +------------+        +------------+        +------------+
     |   Next     |------->|   Next     |------->|   Next     |--->NULL   
     +------------+        +------------+        +------------+
```

Now, I bet you can tell what:

> changing `i`, and making `i->next = new` at the end

would do. This isn't a dig or meant to be condescending, it is really the way you need to work out linked-list issues until you have done it enough you can visualize the pointer wiring in your head. This is even more important when you get to circular or doubly-linked list insertions and deletions. No matter what the problem, if you just write it down and label all the connections that are being made or broken, you can then code it cleanly in your editor.

Comment: That ASCII, was truly enlightening! Thank you very much, got it and will start to draw schematics from now on :)

Comment: There is no replacement for good old pencil and paper sometime. I bit the bullet when I had myself so wrapped around the axle trying to figure out list-insertions on a doubly-linked circular list I was ready to scream. After sitting down and drawing out the nodes involved, the pointer connections that were needed -- it all fell into place. The more complex the data structure, the more important the old No. 2 becomes `:p`

Answer (score 1):

with some minors modifications your code is like this

```
void snoc(Lint *l, int val)
{
   Lint i, new;
   new = (Lint) malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
   new->value = val;
   new->next = NULL;
   i = *l;  
   if(!(*l))
   {
     *l = new;
     return;
   }
   while(i->next) i = i->next;   // (1)
   i->next = new;                // (2)
}
```

and, this is its explanation:

In (1) we walk throught the linked list until its end. We know we are at the end because `i->next` (which point after each loop step to the next nodo item) is null so in that case, we make `i->next` point to the newly created nodo item in (2). But `l` never changed during the function, `l` is always pointing to the begining of our linked list so the purpose of this function is to add a new element at the end without changing the value of `l`.

but also we can initialize our linked list with this function...for example:

```
   Lint l = NULL;
   snoc(&l, 10); // l will be initialized with a new nodo item with 10 as the value its value member
```

(0) checks if `l` is null in that case we make `*l` point to the newly allocated nodo item and return...so initialization done.

I add another way for the code above

```
void snoc(Lint *l, int val)
{
   Lint now, new, previous;
   new = (Lint) malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
   new->value = val;
   new->next = NULL;
   if(!(*l)) // (0)
   {
     *l = new;
     return;
   }
   for(now = *l; now; now = now->next)previous = now;
   previous->next = new;
}
```

Comment: Your revised `snoc()` won't work as is... you'd need to change `i` to a `Lint *`, test `*i`, and point `i` at each `next` pointer in the loop (eg: `*i = *l; while(*i) { i = &((*i)->next); } *i = new;`).

Comment: @Dmitri I don't see what you mean... in this code `i = *l` not `i = l` so `i` is of type `Lint` not a  `Lint *` type

Comment: But it *should* be `Lint *`, or you won't modify the `next` pointer of the last node... you'll just point `i` to it and lose it when the function exits.  You can either get a pointer to the last node then set its `next` pointer to the new node (as others are doing), or get a pointer to the last `next` pointer and set that pointer to the new node (which requires another level of indirection).

Comment: no look at this statement `i=*l` we just give `i` the adress of the nodo item `*l` is pointing to it doesn't change the actual value of `l` so `*l` is always pointing to the first nodo item. `(i->next)` is of `Lint` type isn't it? we don't miss anything here while we have the adress of the begining of this linked list, we can always walk trhough the list...

Comment: As is, after your `while` loop, `i` will have the same value as the last node's `next` pointer (which is NULL).  Then you set `i` to point at the new node... but that only modifies `i`, not the last node's `next` pointer.  Yes, you're leaving `*l` unchanged, and finding the end of the list, but you're not actually adding the new node because you don't modify the pointer at the end of the list -- just your local `i`.  That's why you need one more level of indirection to make it work... that or stop at the last node (rather than the last pointer) and set `i->next` instead of `i`.

Comment: @Dmitri no after the `while` loop that we leave when `i` is pointing to nothing, we make `i=new` so we add the new nodo item to the list  and return. `i` is always a member of the linked list. Before (2) `i` is the `next` member of the last nodo item of the non-modified list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78657/discussion-between-narcisse-doudieu-siewe-and-dmitri).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but why don't you simply copy the pointer? You can keep a pointer to the initial element and use a second one to traverse though it.